# smallest value of array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, codeblocks, minimum

I'm trying to write a function that will return the smallest value of an array. So far I have this, but all it returns is 0.

I don't see how it would return 0 since I am using a for loop to cycle through the array. Perhaps it is not cycling through the arrays values as I would think it does. Can anyone elaborate on the logic and the fallacy in this code?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int newArray[9] = {4,5,9,3,6,2,1,7,8};


int minArray()
{
    int index = 1;
    int minimum;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (newArray[i] > newArray[index])
        {
            minimum = newArray[index];
        }
        index++;

    }

    return minimum;
}


int main()    
{   
    cout << "original array:\n ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << newArray[i] << ", ";
    }

    cout << "minimum value of array: ";
    cout << minArray();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be very instructive to step through the program in the debugger and observe what happens at every step. I think this way you'll learn a lot more than if someone points out all the bugs.

Comment: Think about which values you are comparing at each step. Are these the values you want to be comparing? I would recommend using a debugger, or just trying to think through a full cycle of the code, operation by operation, with a piece of paper.

Comment: Also, you should initialize minimum to somw known value.

Comment: a hint: You are updating `index` wrong. Also, You don't actually need the `index` variable at all.

Comment: Thanks guys, I do not know how to work with the debugger yet, I shall learn this as soon as possible.

Comment: @Revoo If the code isn't longer than this, pen & paper is better than a debugger. Just read through it line by line and write down the values of all the variables. Do it first with smaller arrays. Start with `{1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good idea might be to initialize minimum with an element in the array.
So:

```
minimum = newArray[0]
```

In your loop (pseudocode assuming you don't want the answer):

```
if: newArray[pos] < minimum

        minimum = newArray[pos];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `minimum` variable should be initially assigned to a value in the array, then compare each element in the array with `minimum`. If less than, assign `minimum` with that value:

```
int minArray()
{
    int minimum = newArray[0];
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (newArray[i] < minimum)
        {
            minimum = newArray[i];
        }
        index++;

    }
  return minimum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int minArray(int a[], int size) {
    if (size <= 0) return 0; //
    int m = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
       if (a[i] < m) m = a[i];
    }
    return m;
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 4, 3, 6, 2 };
    std::cout << minArray(a, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `minimum` with some known value or with maximum integer value.

```
int minArray()
{
    int minimum = newArray[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (minimum > newArray[i])
        {
            minimum = newArray[i];
        }
    }

    return minimum;
}
```

And you are dealing wrong with `index` (actually you don't need it at all). Example of how `index` can be used instead of `minimum`:

```
int minArray()
{
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (newArray[index] > newArray[i])
        {
            index = i;
        }
    }

    return newArray[index];
}
```

Both examples should work fine, but I recommend to use first.